# Remove characters from a string only when they occur in a certain order in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to clean up this string "cha?ra\ncter num?\nber". I want it to remove "?" and "\n" without removing "n" when it is alone. I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Any advice appreciated!

```
data_doc='cha?ra\ncter num?\nber'
code={"?":"", "\n":""}
table=str.maketrans(code.keys())
data_doc.translate(table)
```

Comment: Instead of giving `code.keys()` try giving `code` itself to `str.maketrans`.

Comment: thanks! glad to know I wasn't too far off...:)

Answer (score 3):

An even shorter way to do this could be to simply use replace

```
data_doc='cha?ra\ncter num?\nber'
data_doc = data_doc.replace('?','').replace('\n','')
```

Output:

```
character number
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
data_doc='cha?ra\ncter num?\nber'
cleaned = re.sub("[\\n\?]", "", data_doc)
print(cleaned)
```

The output:

```
character number
```